# Rails passing string or hash strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

Can I specify using strong parameters either a string or a hash

I have an endpoint for which payload can be either:

```
card: { number: "4111****", exp_year: "12"}
```

or

```
card: "some_encrypted_card"
```

in strong parameters

If I use `permit(:card)` case 1 doesn't work
If I use `require(:card).permit(:number, :exp_year)` case 2 doesn't work

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could interrogate the card param to see what type it returns:

```
def card_params
  if params[:card].is_a? String
    params.permit(:card)
  else
    params.require(:card).permit(:number, :exp_year)
  end
end
```